# Airflow - How to add a new dags?

Tags: google-compute-engine, airflow

I tried to see some questions like for example: [How do I add a new dag to a running airflow service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885844/how-do-i-add-a-new-dag-to-a-running-airflow-service) but I did not succeed!

I uploaded the airflow in a virtual machine by following the steps of that link: https://medium.com/grensesnittet/install-apache-airflow-on-a-google-cloud-platform-virtual-machine-f9a5b01b6c33

And now I need to add new dags that I have created but I do not know how to find them! Could someone help me how to do this?

```
airflow.cfg:
dags_folder = /srv/airflow/dags
```

vm:

```
root@vm-airflow:/srv/airflow# ls
airflow-webserver.pid  airflow.cfg  airflow.db  bin  include  lib  logs  unittests.cfg  webserver.pid  webserver_config.py
```

Comment: can't you just create that directory on your vm and put your dags in there? there's a process that runs occasionally (or when you trigger a dag via the experimental rest api) that reads the dag directory.

Comment: I already changed the path in airflow.cfg, I put a python file with the dag inside but without success!

Comment: you may need to restart your webserver and scheduler to have the new dag collected. Otherwise it should appear.